Does putting foreign keys in another strong entity equal bad design and what is that table?
I see so many tables designed like this:
https://www.quackit.com/sql_server/sql_server_2016/tutorial/create_a_relationship_in_sql_server_2016.cfm

Where the foreign key is dropped into another table which in my mind is a strong entity in itself.
Artists (ArtistId, ArtistName)
Albums (AlbumId, AlbumName, ReleaseDate, ArtistId, GenreId)
Genres (GenreId, Genre)
This design is convenient but what is the Albums table? Is it strong, weak or a linking table?
Rather I would've thought a good design is this:
Artists (ArtistId, ArtistName)
Albums (AlbumId, AlbumName, ReleaseDate)
Genres (GenreId, Genre)
ArtistCreatedAlbum (ArtistId, AlbumId)
AlbumHasGenre (AlbumId, GenreId)
Strong Entity (Artists, Albums, Genres)
Linking Table (ArtistCreatedAlbum, AlbumIsGenre)
Even if this example doesn't make sense. So many designs drop foreign keys into a strongish entity because its convenient.
e.g
Person (id, name, email, car_id, house_id, school_id)
and in my mind that shouldn't be done.

There is nothing wrong with putting the foreign key in the same table, if it's a one-to-many relationship. Just set it to nullable if you want to be able to have the strong entity exist without the FK link. In a manay-to-many relationship you need a junction table, but otherwise it's not necessary.

In your album example: the album table contains real entities, albums. This is pretty directly modelling a real world thing.

e.g Person(id, name, email, car_id, house_id, school_id)
and in my mind that shouldn't be done.

What are you thinking should be done instead?
If you need to link a person to a car then you need a foreign key somewhere otherwise you end up needing to put the person's car's properties in the person record itself.
Though for all those links, I would suggest a many-to-many relationship (a person may have more than one house, a house may house more than one person) for which you need a junction table like:
Person          PersonHouse  
---------       -------------       House
Id (PK)   <---- PersonId (FK)       -------
Forenames       HouseId  (FK) ----> Id (PK)
Surname                             Address
Title

That “PersonHouse” entity may have its own properties depending on what you are trying to model (if they are the owner/renter/dependent/etc, date range of occupation, and so forth) or may just be the pair of FK values if nothing else is relevant in what you are modelling.

Thanks for the response. I would say adding a Junction table is always better design. A FK can appear in a Junction table or a Weak entity table maybe e.g PersonVisitsHouse(PersonId, SalesPersonId, Date) But It seems totally wrong to be putting them in tables that are Strong Entities. Yet so many people do it!

@tickmeister - I would argue that using a junction table where you do not have a many-to-many relationship is incorrect and potentially dangerous, because your model is allowing things that should not happen. You'll end up relying on application logic to enforce the “one” part of one-to-many relationship rules, instead of letting the database do that for you, increasing the chance of bugs being able to let in incorrect data. If you need a one-to-many relationship the FK belongs in the “parent” record, if you need many-to-many then use a junction table. Use the right tool for the job at hand.

I believe you can do all types of relationships in a junction table.  N:M -> (id pk, id2 pk), 1:M -> (id pk, id2), 1:1 (id pk & unique, id2 pk & unique). I know you can embed a FK into another table 1:M but to me it seems less desirable, what if the child doesn't have that relationship causing nulls in the child.

@tickmeister - (in my last I meant to say the FK belongs in the child record, not parent, as I think you spotted). While you can enforce a 1-M in a junction (my mind blanked on unique/pk constraints earlier), I wouldn't unless: ① there are properties of the relationship to store there (so the table is more than a pair of FKs), ② if there is a chance the 1-M will later need to become a M-M, ③ maybe for consistency if there are several M-M rels too. I'd not add the extra work in queries & updates just to avoid NULLs, but that debate is still ongoing from the 70s so opinions do vary markedly.

Thanks for clarifying David, I think you are right. It seems better to put the FK into the child table and let it live there. you won me over on that one. Thanks for your answers

The SQL regime incorporates the concept of linking "records" through references to their "keys". The concept doesn't originate with SQL but is an ancient clerical practice.
The most general form of linkage in SQL is to have a linkage table, in which each entry in this table has two (or more) fields, and each field references a record in a different table.
Applied to the real world, a roll of marriages in an office of public records, is the most obvious manifestation of this form.
However, in the case of one-to-many (or indeed one-to-one) linkages, the additional table can be dispensed with, and instead an additional field for the foreign key can simply be added on the record on the "one" side of the relationship.
This is most appropriate where the linkage would not normally be considered a primary or independent form of record.
For example, unlike a marriage which specifically records a relationship between two people, a birth certificate records mother and father in the same record as the birth itself. There is no separate linkage record for parents in the way there is for spouses.
This is because the parent link is assumed to be set at the time of the birth, and would not be decided separately from the birth or with much need to vary the parentage link independently of the birth record.
A marriage record is not however condensed into a field on the birth record like this (even though it is one-to-one, where the linkage exists), because this would require the birth record to be edited later in life. (Nowadays of course, potentially multiple times.)
Whether your linkages have to change, and whether it is important or not to avoid changing the primary record simply in order to change the linkage, is part of what might go into the decision about whether to fold the linking field into one of the linked records or not.
